# How to try a different XPATH if it doesn't find one in a try block, Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to find a link that goes to a different link. However it can change everytime with one number `/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div[7]/div[5]/span/a` and `/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div[7]/div[6]/span/a`

But there might be even more changes depending on what the user inputs.

```
user_input = input("What movie would you like to filter:")
user_filter_type = input("What would you like to know \nChoose from list shown:\nnudity,\nviolence,\nprofanity,\ndrugs,\nhorror:")
user_filter_type.lower()


driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)  #, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.imdb.com/')

try:
    imdb_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/nav/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/input"))
    )
    imdb_search.send_keys(user_input)
    imdb_search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
except:
    driver.quit()

try:
    first_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a"))
    )
    first_result.click()
except:
    driver.quit()

try:
    parent_guide_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div[7]/div[6]/span/a")) # I need another XPATH if this doesn't work.
    )
    parent_guide_link.click()
except:
    driver.quit()

xpath_for_filter_type = ""

if user_filter_type == "nudity":
    xpath_for_filter_type = "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/section/section[2]"
elif user_filter_type == "violence":
    xpath_for_filter_type = "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/section/section[3]"
elif user_filter_type == "profanity":
    xpath_for_filter_type = "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/section/section[4]"
elif user_filter_type == "drugs":
    xpath_for_filter_type = "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/section/section[5]"
elif user_filter_type == "horror":
    xpath_for_filter_type = "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/section/section[6]"
else:
    print("Invalid choice. Please run program again ;)")



try:
    all_content = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_for_filter_type))
    )
    print(all_content.text)
except:
driver.quit()
```

The code is supposed to get the movie/show the user wants to watch and also gets the filter type they are trying to block, however as you may know, they will be entering different movies/shows, and when finding the parent guide link in the IMDB page for the movie/show, it can change. How do I fix this?

Comment: Look at my explanation. Also, post a question asking only one task. Your code needs to be completely re-written.

Comment: Oh okay, will do next time, and why does my code need to be rewritten?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, don't use the XPath you get from the browser, make your own custom XPath.

You can either create the XPath based on the link text or its class or id or any such property that stays the same irrespective of the position.

I suggest learning the basics of XPath as it would also help you in the long run.

E.g. in this scenario, I would make an XPath like,
`//a[contains(@href, 'violence') and contains(text(), 'Violence')]`

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me, I meant the variable parent_guide_link, so in the try block, the XPATH it is trying to find can change depending on the movie/show the user has entered going from "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div[7]/div[6]/span/a" to "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div[7]/div[5]/span/a", so I am trying to make it so that if the first XPATH isn't found, another XPATH is searched for as well.

Comment: Yaa, I understood that. What I am saying is that never use an xpath which changes randomly, there is always a better way to do that. Never use the xpath taken from the browser as even if the website changes a little bit, your program will break and won't work until you change it. <br>Instead, if you make XPaths using ID/Class or any other attribute or even using containing text, it will even survive some major changes to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a complex locator for the search field, use id.
I'll suggest how to improve this:

```
try:
    imdb_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/nav/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/input"))
    )
    imdb_search.send_keys(user_input)
    imdb_search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
except:
    driver.quit()
```

Look at my code below.

First, you should import `WebDriverWait`, which is also named as explicit wait, and use it for waiting.

Next, use ID and other locators found by you instead of long and unstable generated XPaths.

Also, you do not need to use try/catch everywhere. Selenium already covers exceptions when some elements cannot be found.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.ID, "suggestion-search")))

imdb_search = find_element_by_id("suggestion-search")    
imdb_search.send_keys("Titanic")
imdb_search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.quit()
```

As a beginner, start iteratively from the easiest part and continue only after it really works. Read about [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and [css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) selectors, how to make them stable.
It's difficult only during the first few months, later you'll enjoy finding them.

Comment: I have imported the modules needed, just didn't feel like it was needed in the code, sorry. Also the element I am trying to find does not have an ID, only an XPATH, so how do I make it so that if one XPATH isn't found, another XPATH is found instead?

Comment: Please add html where this elements is located to your question. Add it as you can, I'll help with formatting.

Comment: You can make it with try/except block or if/else statements.

Comment: @vitalis I did, can you check now?